# Increment amount of a particular item on click among many Items

Tags: angular

I am doing a shopping cart using angular 4. In restaurant description section there are listing of many recommended foods. Each and every food item has a increment or decrement button which is to determine how many items will be ordered. This is the Image link below:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uat4Z.jpg

If I am hitting "+" then each and every amount is getting incremented.

After incrementing one item the result is below:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3edI.jpg

restaurant.component.html code:-

```
<div class="res_list">
            <div class="list_col" *ngFor="let popular of popularSection">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <span class="rhover">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="../../../assets/images/rest_prof.jpg">
                                <figcaption>
                                    {{ popular.item_desc }}
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="item-decs-info">
                                <h5><span [ngClass]="{'ft-nonveg' : popular.item_veg , 'ft-veg' : !popular.item_veg }" class="food-type"></span> {{ popular.item_name }}</h5>
                                <span class="sub_info">Quick Bites</span>
                            </div>                                
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-7">
                                    <p class="item-main-price">{{ popular.item_price }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-5">
                                    <div class="cart-action hide-btn fr">
                                        <button class="add-cart" type="button">ADD</button>
                                        <div class="cart-i-q">
                                            <input  
                                            readonly="" 
                                            [value]="noOfItem" 
                                            type="text">
                                            <button (click)="incOrDec()" disabled="" type="button" class="add-i-b valdown">-</button>
                                            <button 
                                            (click)="incOrDec()" 
                                            type="button" 
                                            class="add-i-b valup">+</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <span *ngIf="popular.choice" class="customised-txt">Customisable</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
        </div>
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: it's better if you can post the code

Comment: is this will be ok to understand? @Niladri

Comment: @SandipNag, what is the code in `incOrDec` method?

Comment: public noOfItem:number = 1;

  incOrDec(){
   this.noOfItem++;
  }

Comment: @SandipNag, You are using one variable for all textboxes, thast is why the number is same everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with your code is: you are binding same variable to the all the "number of items" textboxes. So, all the textboxes display same values.

You should have proper names for each method. Have one method to increment and other to decrement.

There are two ways to handle this.

1. Create `popular-item`(or give any name) `component`, which holds each `item` with item image, price, quantity etc. Pass `popularItem` to this component. i.e.

In this `popular-item` component, have variable `noOfItem`, which ensures there is separate `noOfItem` for each item/product.

when you change the item count by clicking on "+" or "-", the count only chnages for this item.

2. Have a property `count` in  each of the item in `popularSection` array.
   Then in `increment` method increase the count of that item.

i.e.

```
<div class="list_col" *ngFor="let popularItem of popularSection">
  ... blah blah blah
   <div class="cart-i-q">
      <input readonly=""  [value]="noOfItem" type="text">
      <button (click)="decrement(popularItem)" disabled="" type="button" class="add-i-b valdown">-</button>
        <button (click)="increment(popularItem)"  type="button" class="add-i-b valup">+</button>
   </div>
... blah blah blah
</div>
```

In component,

```
increment(popularItem) {
  popularItem.count++;
}

decrement(popularItem) {
  popularItem.count--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

used this logic and easy to increment and decrement

```
<button (click)="popular.item_price = popular.item_price + 1" type="button" class="add-i-b valup">+</button>

<button (click)="popular.item_price = popular.item_price - 1" type="button" class="add-i-b valup">-</button>
```

Comment: I am not asking for the price I am asking for the amount of that Item.

Suppose I am incrementing the amount of " Aloo Patty Sub 12 "  it is affecting for all the items.

Please refer these two links:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uat4Z.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3edI.jpg